# wp-cli install plugin in site language

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wp-cli

I want to improve my new Wordpress sites setup, and am working on a script to install Wordpress and common plugins.

My problem is, when I install a plugin from admin panel, by default, it installs a version of my plugin in the same language as Wordpress is. This is important, for example, in plugin *Contact form 7* it sets up a contact form already configured in that language.

But if I use `wp-cli` to download and activate the plugin, it downloads an English version.

```
wp plugin install contact-form-7 --activate
```

I thought I could use the URL provided in the official Wordpress plugin page, [in my country](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/), but as it has a specific version number, it makes it difficult automation to request always last version, which is my goal:

```
wp plugin install --activate https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/contact-form-7.5.1.3.zip
```

(anyway, this link also leads to an English version of the plugin, even if it was referred from an Spanish Wordpress site)

So, is there any workaorund for this?

Comment: The last example [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/language/) may help, though I've never used it so I cannot be sure. This one: `wp language plugin install akismet nl_NL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've downloaded and activated the plugin use `wp language plugin install contact-form-7 nl_NL` to install the desired translation.

```
# Install and activate the Dutch core language pack.
$ wp language core install nl_NL --activate

# Install and activate Contact Form 7.
$ wp plugin install contact-form-7 --activate

# Provide the Dutch language pack for Contact Form 7.
$ wp language plugin install contact-form-7 nl_NL
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/language/

Comment: That's it, just a note after testing it: it's better to install plugin without the `--activate` option, then install the language pack and **finally** execute `wp plugin activate`, as (at least in this case, but I guess it's frequent), activation implies some actions in which locale is important. (in this specific case a contact form is created in plugin language)